# Batch add intro and outro to videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, editing

I have 500+ videos. I need to add intro and outro to them.

Found this .bat script on a different website, and tried it. But it didn't work for me. As the script only ads outro - still didn't work.

```
SET RESOLUTION="1280:720"
SET INPUT_FOLDER="input"
SET INTRO="intro.mp4"
SET OUTPUT_FOLDER="output"

for %%a in ("%INPUT_FOLDER%\*.*") do ffmpeg -i %INTRO% -i "%%a" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=%RESOLUTION%:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=%RESOLUTION%:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0]; [1:v]scale=%RESOLUTION%:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=%RESOLUTION%:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1]; [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] "%OUTPUT_FOLDER%\%%~na.mp4"
```

I'm on Windows OS, but I also have Linux Mint installed on my workstation.

My question is: how to add 1 intro and 1 outro to 500+ videos?

**PS:** Intro and Outro files are the same file.

Thank you.

Comment: No errors or log? Is the problem with your batch script or the ffmpeg command?

Comment: I ran the .bat file, but it didn't give me any error. Have to mention the batch script is located in the same place as the video files and intro/outro file -> 4 videos in total for testing purpose. I have no log.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install ffmpeg? This script uses it so it'd be good to have it...

The Idea is that you create a txt-document with all the file-names inside, which will then get stitched together. You can read up on how it works here:

> https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate